# Click on table cells and handle class changes per cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table looking like this:

```
<table class="ui celled table unstackable" id="tblHits">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>40</th>
                <th>40</th>
                <th>40</th>
                <th>25</th>
                <th>15</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="addNone" id="t01">01</td>
                <td class="addNone" id="t02">02</td>
                <td class="addNone" id="t03">03</td>
                <td class="addNone" id="t04">04</td>
                <td class="addNone" id="t05">05</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

What I want to do is to click TD with ID=t01 to change that class from one to another. The classes are defined to only change background colors. I have added some code to actually be able to select one TD already, but for some reason, I'm not able to click TD with id=t03 after that. Nothing happens. Any ideas on how I can do that?

My script is this:

```
$("#tblHits:has(td)").click(function(e) {
    var clickedCell= $(e.target).closest("td");
    if ( $('#t'+ clickedCell.text() + '').hasClass( "addNone" )) {
         $("#tblHits td").removeClass("addNone");
         $('#t'+ clickedCell.text() + '').addClass("addHit");
         alert('Clicked table cell value is: <b> ' + clickedCell.text());
    }
    else if ( $('#t'+ clickedCell.text() + '').hasClass( "addHit" )) {

         $("#tblHits td").removeClass("addHit");
         $('#t'+ clickedCell.text() + '').addClass("addMiss");
         alert('Clicked table cell value is: <b> ' + clickedCell.text());
     }
     else if ( $('#t'+ clickedCell.text() + '').hasClass( "addMiss" )) {
         $("#tblHits td").removeClass("addMiss");
         $('#t'+ clickedCell.text() + '').addClass("addNone");
         alert('Clicked table cell value is: <b> ' + clickedCell.text());
     });
```

Thank you in advance for any feedback concerning this issue!

Comment: You want to change the class after the click on the specific `td` or after clicking on the table?

Comment: after clicking a specific <td>. it should add classes based on the one i am clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use "event delegation" to listen to clicks on a higher element (you did this, listening to clicks on the table).
However, fetching the clicked cell doesn't seem to work as planned.

You could just check if the clicked element is the `td` you want, and work from there. This also gives a small performance boost, since you can exit the script if something is clicked that you are not interested about.

```js
$('#tblHits').on('click', function (evt) {
    var $td = $(evt.target);
    if (!$td.is('td')) return;

    if ($td.hasClass('addNone')) {
       $td.removeClass('addNone').addClass('addHit');
    } else
    if ($td.hasClass('addHit')) {
       $td.removeClass('addHit').addClass('addMiss');
    } else
    if ($td.hasClass('addMiss')) {
       $td.removeClass('addMiss').addClass('addNone');
    }
});
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bkry0txr/4/

btw, I'd advice adding another selector to the `td`, eg. another classname. 
For example:

```html
<tr>
  <td class="hitbox addNone"></td>
  <td class="hitbox addHit"></td>
  <!-- etc -->
</tr>
```

And then the JS:

```js
$('#tblHits').on('click', function (evt) {
    var $td = $(evt.target);
    if (!$td.is('.hitbox')) return;
    // etc..
});
```

This way you can have other `td` elements, or even change to other elements if you'd like. The JS doesn't need to change, as long as the element you want to check have the classname `hitbox`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The code works perfectly! But how should i use the td.selector you mentioned? instead of the first if sentence you wrote?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't that clear. I modified the answer to explain what I mean. If my answer helped you, could you upvote please? Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the edit. Ill upvote this of curse.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a click event on all your `td`, and for each one, you can change your css as you like!

There is no need to use this `$('#t'+ clickedCell.text())`.

```
$( "td" ).each(function(index) {
  $(this).on("click", function(){

    if ($(this).hasClass('addNone')) {
       $(this).removeClass('addNone').addClass('addHit');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('addHit')) {
       $(this).removeClass('addHit').addClass('addMiss');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('addMiss')) {
       $(this).removeClass('addMiss').addClass('addNone');
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: it seems to work on click, but it for some reason doesnt handle it as i hoped. its adding the classes a bit randomly it seems. But I also found out that i removed the class from wrong parameter. its shouldnt remover from $("#tblHits td").removeClass("addNone"); but instead   $('#t'+ clickedCell.text() + '').removeClass("addNone").